# Possible use of isolated し?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

I came across a sentence that doesn't make sense no matter how I try to break it up. The context is a person's reply to a question about cutting their hair.

切るタイミング逃しちゃっただけ。

I'm not 100% sure whether the や and つ are little or big from the handwriting, but I'm pretty sure the above is correct.

The first and last parts are easy.

切る  タイミング  ...  だけ。

However, I'm not aware of any words that follow up a 逃 with し, so I suppose maybe it stands alone. In that case it's probably:

切る  タイミング  逃  し  ちゃった  だけ。

However, I usually see し at the end of the sentence terminating a list.

(On a side note, I'm not sure how the English word is being used here either.)

Answer (score 7):

逃し is `のがし` from [逃]{のが}す.  逃しちゃった is a contraction of 逃してしまった.  So this し is just okurigana, not a standalone particle.

Comment: 逃し is the 連用形 of 逃す, also known as the masu-stem form

Comment: @user11589:  You are right, but that is not the case here.  As I said, it's using a contraction of 〜てしまった, so we're dealing with the て形, not the 連用形.

Comment: I was focusing on the し in 逃し in your answer, my apologies

Comment: So, it would translate something like: "It's just that it's about time to stop losing it." Is that right?

Comment: Or no...  More like "It's just that the timing of the cut stopped..." I don't know.

Comment: のがす means "to let get away" or something like that. 切{き}る in this case means "to do something before time is up," so a translation would probably go something like "I just ended up letting the timing to do it get away." That's a pretty awkward, overly-literal translation, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: So, 切るタイミング means cutting the time in a more metaphysical sense. What, then is the function of the しまった? What is stopping?

Comment: しまった here means the situation was unfortunate, not that something was stopping.

Comment: In the Japanese grammar as is taught at school in Japan, both ます形 and て形 are considered to be two different forms of 連用形, because they were the same form in Classical Japanese. (This might be different from how the Japanese grammar is taught when people learn Japanese as a foreign language, though.) So you are right that the 逃し in 逃しちゃった is the て形 of 逃す, but you have to be careful when you say it is not 連用形.

Comment: タイミングを逃す is "miss the timing/opportunity". The sentence says "I just missed the timing to cut my hair."

Comment: Then why is 切る at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: ^切る is modifying タイミング.